# React Native mapped array objects inside style array?

Tags: arrays, react-native, styles

Been trying to work this out for a couple hours now and no dice.
Everything works except the style array. Not sure how to include the mapped array objects in the style array?

Error: `Failed prop type: Invalid props.style...`

So the `<Text Style={` array format is incorrect but I don't know the correct syntax to convert it. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
const navTabs = [ {label: 'Home'}, {label: 'Next'} ]
const { Home, Next } = styles

{navTabs.map(x => 
<TouchableOpacity key={x.label} onPress={ () => navigate(`${x.label}`)}> 
<Text style={ [ navTxt, `${x.label}` ] }> {x.label} </Text> 
</TouchableOpacity> )}

const styles = { navTxt:{backgroundColor:'#000', paddingHorizontal: 5}, Home:{color: 'red'}, Next:{color: 'white'} }
```

Comment: why are you using `x.label` as style which is not a style? `<Text style={[styles.navTxt]} />` should works.

Comment: @Val cause there are two styles applied to `<Text>` - normally it would be an array `style={ [navTxt, Home] }` or `[navTxt, Next]` but cause I am mapping over the `const navTabs` to populate, the navigate function and interpolate the label string and the style attribute, x.label derives from the .map function. check the working solution below provided by @soutot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be honest it looks odd for me, but I think this is what you want to achieve

Update: 
there's a workaround you can do, as following

```
render() {
const navTabs = [
  { label: 'Home' },
  { label: 'Next' },
];
const styles = {
  Home: {
    color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
  },
  Next: {
    color: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
  },
  navTxt: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
  },
};

return (
     {navTabs.map(x =>
          <TouchableOpacity key={x.label} onPress={() => {}}>
            <Text style={{ ...styles.navTxt, ...styles[x.label] }}> {x.label} </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
);
}
```

Comment: I should have also included the navTxt styles to identify the need for [navTxt, x.label] but work on the basis they are backgroundColor etc

Comment: updated the question with all related styles as mentioned above

Comment: @Max Great. That's it. For some reason native-base Text doesn't allow you to use arrays in style property. So this workaround can get things to work
It's good to mention if you are using the Text component from React Native, then this solution should be fine:
<Text style={[styles.navTxt, styles[x.label]]}> {x.label} </Text>

Answer (score 0):

Each element in the style array must be either an object or a StyleSheet. Something like this:

```
style = StyleSheet.create({ navTxt: { color: 'red' } })

<Text style={ [ style.navTxt, { label: x.label } ] }> {x.label} </Text>
```

Comment: now the error is: invalid props.style key 'label' supplied to Text

Comment: All right, I wrote this for an example. You must select the desired value from the available list: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style

Comment: some as `fontSize` or `fontWeight`.

Comment: whats the equivalent syntax of `${x.label}` inside the style array? not sure i understand your reference. two styles would be Text style={[one, two]} but in this case the second style is being interpolated from the .map function. To "select the desired value from the available list" ...sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: `${x.label}` -- what is it? It is not text style! It is string. U object like this: Object.assign(navTxt, 'Home').  But it is wrong, no strings, only object. 

What do u want? I do not understand

Comment: Yes! [one, two]
one: object ({})
two: object ({}) BUT u want do this: one: ?, two: STRING